# How to Send email automatically once order complete?

Tags: php, ecommerce-tracking, magento-1.3

Hi guys and girls just wondering how do you get Magento to send an email by itself once the order has been marked completed?

Also, whilst im at it: does magento have the capacity to edit the order statuses?

want to remove some of these statuses: they are not needed.

[image]

Okay, so I have been digging in further but no closer to the answer, but possible question which in return could help is how do I edit the list of filter options for order status?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to automatically send an e-mail when the status changes. There are possible solutions depending on your requirements. An orders status generally changes to complete when an order has an invoice and is shipped, both shipment and invoice e-mails can be sent. If you are manually changing the statuses, you can tick the box to notify the customer. If your automating the status change in custom code you could add code to send a message.

For your second question, what management you can do of order statuses can be found in `System > Order Statuses`. There are also often options for the statuses assigned to your orders when they are created in the individual payment methods. `System > Configuration > Payment Methods > Some Method`.

Comment: Cheers, I had thought the same, so good to confirm.

Comment: Sorry, pal seems like system > order statuses is not present, Magento ver. 1.3.2.4 is what we are using currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create an Observer and listen for *sales_order_save_after* event and depending on the status/state change send the email.

```
public function exampleEventHandler(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    $state = 'state_you_want';
    // Only trigger when an order enters processing state.
    if ($order->getState() == $state && $order->getOrigData('state') != $state) {
        // send email 
    }
}
```

https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/

Regarding adding custom Order States to Magento try something like this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-order-state/

Comment: Ahhh okay, so if I wanted the email to send when order has been sent out for delivery would I use the complete state ?